# How to read system variable into a conf file in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration-files

I would read an environment variable like this below

```
my.key = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}
```

But how to read a system variable that's passed in via

```
-Dmysystem.var=XXX
```

It is not being resolved in my conf file

Comment: what does your System.getProperty("mysystem.var") returns?

Comment: I want to read it in the conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your project is managed via SBT. make sure you have the following set in the build file

```
javaOptions in Global += "-Dmysystem.var=XXX"
```

and your application.conf file has the following

```
my_key=${mysystem.var}
```

and now you should be able to be refer the `my_key` using the below code

```
configuration.getString("my_key")
```

tested this in my play app and it is working as expected.